# Azure Maps Search API's response language not always english

Tags: azure, azure-maps

The response of Maps Search Reverse API gives results in the country's local language, how can I force it to respond in English only? Google's API does not have this issue.

Here is the API's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressreverse#uri-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't yet documented as work on localizing data globally is still being done, but you can try this out by adding "&language=" and passing in a language IDs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-languages

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually worked. I was trying with &culture=en-US but &language=en just worked perfectly. Thanks again.